# Паттерн для формирования массива конфигураций

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, шаблоны-проектирования

Имею UITableView. Делаю кастомный объект в котором будут содержаться проперти для конфигурирования кастомных ячеек для таблицы. Объект выглядит следующим образом:

```
@interface CellDescription : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property BOOL visible;
@property int cellType;
@property int ID;
@property int numChildrens;
@property BOOL switch;
@property int closed;

@end
```

в .m только @synthesize, больше ничего нет. Объекты сейчас делаю так:

```
- (void) configureObjects {
CellDescription *cd = [CellDescription new];
cd.text = @"Текст";
cd.cellType = 1;
cd.ID = 0;

CellDescription *cd1 = [CellDescription new];
cd1.text = @"Текст";
cd1.cellType = 3;
cd1.ID = 1;

....
   // еще много таких объектов
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:cd, cd1, ... , nil];
}
```

После создания массива из таких объектов и пробегая по нему в `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` формирую таблицу с кастомными ячейками. Все хорошо кроме того что метод в котором я формирую эти объекты руками (контент ячеек статический) занимает три четверти .m-файла а хочется сделать красиво. Как поступить правильно чтобы очистить .m от этого кода оставив только логику для таблицы? Сделать отдельный класс и потом вызывать оттуда этот метод для заполнения массива или есть какой-то паттерн для таких случаев?

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите немного кода, чтобы было более понятно, как выглядит ваш "объект, в котором".

Comment: Подозреваю что ТС надо просто создать потомка UITableViewCell и в нем настроить кастомный вид ячеек, но для уточнения действительно нужен пример кода

Comment: этого кода достаточно? Есть ли еще мнения помимо ответа Чингис Гомбоев?

Comment: Готовлю вам обстоятельный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую описать более детально то, что **@Чингис Гомбоев** и **@aknew** вместе уже обрисовали вам в общем виде. Данный паттерн не является чем-то новым, его использование как раз и предполагается архитектурой `UITableViewController+UITableView+UITableViewCell`.

Итак, начнём.

Вот стандартная структура метода `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourViewCell *cell = (YourViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:YourCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[YourViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:YourCellIdentifier];
    } 

    /* Настраиваем cell в соответствии с конкретным данным indexPath */

    return cell;
}
```

Данная структура предполагает, что мы не создаём наши ячейки-Cells каждый раз заново, а берём их по возможности из кэша, который пополняется из ячеек, который в данный момент не видны/перестали быть видны на экране. Таким образом получается, что tableview data source (то есть источник данных - в вашем случае это ваш массив состоящий из объектов CellDescription) может содержать 100 объектов, но реально в памяти будут находиться лишь те ячейки, которые видны на экране, скажем 3 или 5 штук. Очевидно, что это придумано для экономии памяти, т.к. стоит вам убрать это кэширование, и вы достаточно быстро увидите, что памяти начинает быстро нехватать (несколько сотен ячеек и приложение начнёт крашиться)

Обратите внимание на метод `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` - он смотрит кэш на предмет наличия в нём ячеек с пометкой `YourCellIdentifier` (вдруг у вас есть несколько видов ячеек - тогда по одному Identifier на каждый тип ячейки), и, если такой элемент в нём есть, возвращает его вам - то есть вы уже имеете ранее созданный и инициализированный объект Cell, и вам достаточно лишь заполнить полями для данного indexPath. Если же в кэше готовой ячейки нет, тогда придётся создавать её заново.

Из этого паттерна есть маленькое следствие, которое вытекает из этой истории с кэшированием:

Вам нужно (точнее мне кажется, что нужно, так как это очень естественно в связи с идей кэширования описанной выше), чтобы ваша ячейка (её нужно делать подклассом `UITableViewCell`) должна содержать два публичных метода: один для инициализации вашей ячейки - вы создаёте всю её view-иерархию: текстовые поля, картинки, прочее содержимое ПОКА ЧТО БЕЗ НАПОЛНЕНИЯ, а второй для заполнения уже созданной ячейки конкретной информации.

Результат: теперь в **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**,когда ячейка будет создаваться в первый раз: вы будете её инициализировать её первым методом, и заполнять вторым, а далее, когда dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier будет вам возвращать эту ячейку из кэша (как она туда попала? - вы прокрутили далеко - и она оказалась не нужна), вы будете только лишь заполнять её вторым методом (первый не нужен - она уже инициализована!).

Итак, ключевой код:

```
// YourViewCell.h
#import "CellDescription.h"

@interface YourViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)fillWithCellDescription:(CellDescription *)cellDescription;

/* Скорее всего очень много всяких label, картинок и пр. в виде атрибутов @property... */

@end

// YourViewCell.m
@implementation YourViewCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        /* Здесь вы инициализируете вашу ячейку: вы создаёте _неизменное_: всё то, что может быть использовано заново без изменений */
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)fillWithCellDescription:(CellDescription *)cellDescription {
    /* Здесь вы делаете заполнение вашей ячейки конкретным содержимым cellDescription */
}

@end
```

Теперь код вашего вашего контроллера (скорее всего подкласса `UITableViewController`), который служит делегатом (`delegate`) и источником данных (`dataSource`) для вашего table view:

```
// YourTableViewController.h
@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *cellDescriptions
@end

// YourTableViewController.m
static NSString *YourCellIdentifier = @"YourCell";

@implementation YourTableViewController 

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self) {
        // Важно! Мы регистрируем YourViewCell с меткой YourCell, чтобы с ним можно было работать из кэша
        [self.tableView registerClass:PlaceViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier: YourCellIdentifier];

        self.cellIdentifiers = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourViewCell *cell = (YourViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:YourCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Создаём заново
        cell = [[YourViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:YourCellIdentifier];
    } else {
        // В кэше уже есть, ничего не делаем, так как имеем готовый cell из кэша
    }

    // Заполняем кокретным содержимым
    CellDescription *cellDescription = [self.cellDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell fillWithCellDescription:cellDescription]

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Теперь ответ на эту часть вашего вопроса:

```
Как поступить правильно чтобы очистить .m от этого кода оставив только логику для таблицы.
```

Вам нужно убрать весь этот код внутрь YourViewCell, в его вторую часть fillWithCellIdentifier.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ 1**

Я пока что оставил за кадром вопрос формирования self.cellIdentifiers. Если этот вопрос тоже интересен, можно сообщить мне об этом в комментариях.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Великолепное объяснение техники с повторным использованием View-элементов: 
[How to reuse/recycle custom element like uitableviewcell does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914427/how-to-reuse-recycle-custom-element-like-uitableviewcell-does?rq=1)

А вот как я сам вышел на эту тему в связи с производительностью и крашами от нехватки памяти: [A faster way to create complex view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825354/a-faster-way-to-create-complex-uiview)

Comment: Очень много правок, приношу извинения. Скоро всё утрясётся.

Comment: В моём ответе есть несколько дополнительных деталей. Мне бы помогла обратная связь для того, чтобы знать, что именно прояснить/уточнить.

Comment: Большое спасибо за более чем обстоятельный ответ, Stanislaw! Моя задача была написать не просто таблицу с разным контентом в ячейках а и помимо этого сделать выпадающие таблицы на некоторых ячейках, и еще много всего. Поэтому я храню конфигурации каждой ячейки в child-обьектах CellDescription которыми заполнен массив и в -cellForRowAtIndexPath формирую ячейки по значениям пропертей объектов из массива. Все это уже реализовано, вопрос был только о том куда спрятать шаблонный код для установки значений каждого из сорока объектов подальше от UITableViewController

Answer (score 1):

Заметь что у `UITableView` есть свойства `delegate` и `dataSource`,
наверняка обоим этим свойствам ты присвоил `self`, т.е. сам контроллер в котором находится сама таблица. `delegate` обрабатывает все взаимодействие с пользователем, а `datasource` отвечает за заполнение контента для таблицы (в данном случае из твоего массива).
Для красоты кода просто создай отдельный класс для `dataSource`, задаешь его для таблицы как `dataSource` и 
в нем определишь все нужные методы `UITableViewDataSource` ( ну типа – `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` или – `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`), массив желательно тоже хранить в нем